# Display how many reviews there are for a CPT

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two custom post types, 'product' and 'product_review'. The CPT 'product_review' has a taxonomy 'product_name' whose slug matches the CPT 'product'

An example 'Product A' is the product post. 'Product Review A' is the product_review post that has a 'product_name' taxonomy value of 'product_a'.

I need to show how many 'product_review' each 'product' has.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
    //echo $post_slug; 
    //this outputs the name of the product, which I need

    $terms = get_terms('product_review');
    foreach ( $terms as $post_slug ) {
    echo $term->count . 'Reviews';
?>
```

It doesn't show any count. I want it to show how many $terms(how many reviews) are tied to $post_slug(name of product). The 'product_review' slug matches the slug of the product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `WP_Query` and the `found_posts` prop like below:

```
// example query args
$args = [
    // look for reviews cpt
    'post_type' => 'product_review',

    // limit to posts that match our taxonomy product name
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_name',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ 'product_a' ]
        ]
    ]
];

// run the query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// grab "total" found posts
$total = $query->found_posts;

// display the total
echo $total

// reset post data so we dont break the main loop
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This is already inside a query / loop. Will this still work or cannot be done another way?

Comment: Yes this should work in a loop.  Updated my answer to include `wp_reset_postdata` to better play inside a loop.

Comment: to keep this dynamic, just pull out the slug for the parent post and use that for the 'terms' correct? These are tiles, and aprx 40 on the page each one with a review count. I can access the slug and match it to the 'terms' w/no issue. Just want to make sure that is correct way. Thanks for the assistance, learned more new WP techniques.

Answer (score 0):

@mikerojas answer got me close, but wasn't returning accurate data. Here is what I came up with that got me what I needed.

```
<?php
    $review_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array (
                            'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            //this is already inside a loop, making it dynamic to only grab the reviews whose tax value equals the post slut
                            'terms' => $post->post_name,
                    )
            ),
    );
    if($num = count( get_posts ( $review_args)) <= 1) {
            echo 'Review ' . $num = count( get_posts( $review_args ) );
    } else {
            echo 'Reviews ' . $num = count( get_posts( $review_args ) );
    }
                                                
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```